# How to find the theta notation given the summation

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Can someone explain in detail how to go from summation to theta notation by going through part (a), which tells us to find the asymptotically tight $\Theta$ bound for
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2$$

[Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAIqS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the definition of Big Theta notation. If we have 
$$g(n)=\Theta(f(n))$$
Then this means that there exists positive constants $a$ and $b$ such that for $n>N$, we have
$$a \cdot f(n)<g(n)<b \cdot f(n)$$
So for your part (a), we can rewrite the summation as
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}$$
Thus for large $n$, the $n^3$ term dominates, so we have
$$\frac{1}{3}n^3 < \frac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}<\frac{1}{2}n^3$$
And thus we have 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n i^2 = \Theta(n^3)$$